# Windows Authentication MVC 4 Intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

In a mvc 4 intranet site is, how would you force the user to enter windows credentials when the app loads for say the Home Controller Index Action.  It seems as though the browser is remembering the password.  If so, can you disable the browsers' from remembering?

I am using IIS Express.

I have allow anonymous authentication disabled
windows authentication enabled
and the Index Action for the Home Controller has the Authorize attribute. (now trying controller level)

I thought that forces to Enter credentials.

I was following this
http://www.itorian.com/2013/05/windows-authentication-in-mvc4-with-iis.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />    
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Controller

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing: why are you posting your source as images? To avoid remembering passwords while testing, try incognito mode. To avoid this in deployed version, you could probably save login cookie as session, this means that it will get deleted after the user closes web browser. I have never tried this in asp.net, I only know the concept from PHP.

Comment: updated with code, but it is not prompting me to enter them, it is just  logging me right in.

Comment: Does it at least use the right credentials, so you login with the user you're accessing the page, or it doesn't restrict the access at all?

Comment: it logs in correctly with my windows credentials and displays my login name correctly.  I just want it to prompt for credentials.

Comment: @user1307149 so you don't want Integrated Windows Security? You know that this will piss off users right?

Answer (score 1):

This is me just guessing as you haven't provided `<appSettings>` part:

The [guide](http://www.itorian.com/2013/05/windows-authentication-in-mvc4-with-iis.html) (it's same link as you've provided) says that you should've set these 2 values:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

This is the only thing that comes to mind and every source I could find points to `autoFormsAuthentication` change.

Another thing I've found is [Microsoft's guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). It's fo MVC 3, but I don't thing there were any major changes regarding this. It's longer than your original tutorial, but it covers all the setup and explains everything you need to do.

Comment: That is what I was seeing as well and reposted the above config file

Comment: @user1307149, I've updated the answer, please look into it and let me know how it turned out.

Comment: will do ill give this a shot, this is one I have not found.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you know why the prompt appears, you know how to turn it on and off,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063

> The following conditions must be met for Internet Explorer to
>   automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain
>   security:
>
> - Windows Integrated authentication, also known as Windows NT
>     Challenge/Response, must be enabled in the Web site properties in IIS.
>     Anonymous authentication is attempted first, followed by Windows
>     Integrated authentication, Digest authentication (if applicable), and
>     finally Basic (clear text) authentication.
> - Both the client and the Web
>     server must be either in the same Microsoft Windows NT-based or
>     Microsoft Windows 2000-based domain or in trusted Windows NT-based or
>     Windows 2000-based domains in which the user's account can be granted
>     permissions to resources on the IIS-based computer.
> - The user's browser
>     must be Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer is the only browser that
>     supports Windows Integrated authentication (NTCR).
> - Internet Explorer
>     must consider the requested URL to be on the intranet (local). If the
>     computer name portion of the requested URL contains periods (such as
>     http://www.microsoft.com and 10.0.0.1), Internet Explorer
>     assumes that the requested address exists on the Internet and does not
>     pass any credentials automatically. Addresses without periods (such as
>     webserver) are considered to be on the intranet (local);
>     Internet Explorer passes credentials automatically. The only exception
>     is addresses included in the Intranet zone in Internet Explorer.
> - Internet Explorer's Intranet zone security setting must be set to
>     Automatic logon only in Intranet zone. This is the default setting for
>     Internet Explorer. For additional information about Internet Explorer
>     security zones, click the article number below to view the article in
>     the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> > 174360 How to Use Security Zones in
> >     Internet Explorer
> >
> > The user requesting the Web page must have
> >     appropriate file system (NTFS) permissions to the Web page as well as
> >     all of the objects referenced in the Web page. For example, a user may
> >     have Full Control rights to a Web page, but is prompted for a password
> >     if the Web page refers to graphics that are in a secure folder.

If you intentionally break any of the above condition, you can trigger the prompt.